# Calculating DateTime with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables TimeSheet and TimeRecord. TimeRecord has Foreign Key TimeSheetId of TimeSheet. The following time-logs are from TimeRecord,

TimeSheet sample data:

```
TimeSheetId, StudentId

  187 , 10
  196 , 11
  195 , 12
```

TimeRecord sample data:

```
TimeRecordId  TimeSheetId       TimeIn                 TimeOut

   1             187    8/17/2010 1:06:55 PM    8/17/2010   1:53:49 PM

   2             196    8/17/2010 1:31:28 PM    8/17/2010   4:59:58 PM
   3             187    8/17/2010 1:51:40 PM    8/17/2010   4:59:02 PM
   4             187    8/17/2010 2:13:35 PM    8/17/2010   5:00:08 PM
   5             196    8/17/2010 2:19:44 PM    8/17/2010   5:00:14 PM
   6             196    8/17/2010 2:23:02 PM    8/17/2010   4:46:00 PM
   7             195    8/17/2010 3:04:15 PM    8/17/2010   4:58:34 PM
```

I'd like to get total time spent of each student. So, the result will be like something's like the following:

```
  10 has 10hr 30mn 5sec 
  11 has 8hr 45mm 23sec
  12 has 2hr 33mn 25sec
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are trying to archive:

```
    Dim query = From ts In db.TimeSheet _
                 Join tr In db.TimeRecord On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _
                 Group By ts.StudentId, tr.TimeSheetId Into TotalTime = Sum(DateDiffSecond(tr.TimeIn, tr.TimeOut)) _
                 Select StudentId, TimeSheetId, TotalTime

    Dim timespan As TimeSpan
    Dim formattedTimeSpan As String

    For Each q In query

        timespan = timespan.FromSeconds(q.TotalTime)
        formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0} hr {1} mm {2} sec", Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours), timespan.Minutes)
        Response.Write("Student " & " " & q.StudentId & " has " & q.TimeSheetId & " : " & formattedTimeSpan & "<br/>")

    Next
```

You need to import SqlMethods:

> `Imports System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods`

Also Check out:

- [LINQ to SQL Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085.aspx)
- [SqlMethods Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx)
- [System.DateTime Methods (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply subtract one date from the other.  This will give you a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object. You can then use the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tostring.aspx) method of the TimeSpan object to display the time spent however you wish using [standard TimeSpan format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx).  Your might look something like this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpent = studentTimeRecord.TimeOut - studentTimeRecortd.TimeIn; 
string displayTime = timeSpent.ToString("[hh]hr [mm]mn [ss]sec");
```

Update:
I just realized that I did not address the issue of grouping the students and summing over the grouping.  I'll defer to Jon's answer for that.

Comment: Thanks for this. My question is about summing total time spent of each student from TimeRecord. One TimeSheet can have one ore more TimeRecord.

Comment: If you that method, you can only format TimeSpan < 24hr only. According to the question, student can have total time of more than 24 hr.

Comment: @Angkor Wat, good point.  The link that I included to the standard TimeSpan format strings includes the option for days.  I just tried to duplicate the results in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how well it will work, but I'd at least *try*:

```
var query = from record in db.TimeRecords
            group record by record.TimeSheetId into g
            select new { id = g.Key, 
                         TotalTime = g.Sum(x => x.TimeOut - x.TimeIn) } into t
            join student in db.TimeSheets
            on t.id equals student.TimeSheetId
            select new { student.StudentId, t.TotalTime };
```

It really depends on whether LINQ to SQL is happy to subtract one DateTime from another and then sum the results of doing that across multiple records. (If it works, `TotalTime` should end up as a `TimeSpan`.)

Comment: I'm trying to convert this to VB.NET version. If possible, please give VB.NET equivalent to C# above also. I'm very new to C#. I've just started 3 days ago with C#.

Comment: @Narazana: I don't have time to convert it myself at the moment - but I suggest you *try* it in C# (just in a console app) before worrying about converting it. If it's not going to work, there's no point in converting it :)